# DataGrid can't type in comma or dots as value?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, converters

I got the following code. If I now try to type in a comma or a dot into my "EK-Preis" column, which is a double, it doesnt work. I just can write numbers or letters. If I type in a letter, the cell gets a red contour, which is perfect. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
        private void dgFolien_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataContext as DataRowView;
        try
        {
            if (drv != null)
            {
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var1", drv["Hersteller"].ToString()));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var2", drv["Serie"].ToString()));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var3", drv["Farbe"].ToString()));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var4", drv["EK-Preis"].ToString()));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var5", drv["FolienID"].ToString()));


                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Folien SET Hersteller=@var1, Serie=@var2, Farbe=@var3, [EK-Preis] = @var4 WHERE FolienID=@var5";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
```

And here my XAML:

```
       <DataGrid x:Name="dgFolien" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Height="268" Margin="10,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="489" ColumnWidth="*" RowEditEnding="dgFolien_RowEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hersteller" Binding="{Binding Hersteller, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serie" Binding="{Binding Serie, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Farbe" Binding="{Binding Farbe, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="EK-Preis" Binding="{Binding EK-Preis, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about the actual problem, but in these lines `drv["Hersteller"].ToString()` you take the properties of your drv and do them all `.ToString()`. Database commands created this way generally infer their type from the given object; I'm fairly sure none of these fields can be seen as numeric that way; they're all given as strings.

Comment: I tried it with                         cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var4", Convert.ToDouble(drv["EK-Preis"])));
Doesnt work.
My application wont let me type in a comma or a dot into a cell.

Comment: Of course, I don't know what the database is like. Could be all these things ARE strings in your DB. but if not, well, from what I can see, you're passing them all on as strings. I'm not too familiar with the way wpf does these things, but if some of them are doubles, I think you need to somehow define the types of all columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` forces to process text on every keystroke. 
Change it to `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `LostFocus` . For example if your value is 12.45, the moment `'.'` is detected it expects 45 to be a property binded to 12.

Comment: "For example if your value is 12.45. The moment '.' is detected it expects 45 to be a property binded to 12". I don't think it works like this, datagrid won't create a binding here. More likely "the moment dot is typed after 12 datagrid still interpret it as value 12 and display formatted value without dot"

Comment: as an alternative solution to changing UpdateSourceTrigger set `Delay` property of Binding (.net 4.5) `{Binding Farbe, Delay=400, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }`. type `1`, `2` wait a bit (0.5 sec), type `.`, wait again - dot disappears!

Comment: Kindly refer to this question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273543/wpf-datagrid-validation-binding-mode-bug
This is indeed what happens.